# LinearLayoutManager is not work in RecycleView in Android (Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview

I am creating customAdapter for my `RecyclerView` for the purpose of Loading More data after the Scroll. So I have to `AddScrollListner` on `RecycleView`. But in my public Constructor it not found.

**Android code :**

```
public UserAdapter() {
            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                    totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                        if (mOnLoadMoreListener != null) {
                            mOnLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                        }
                        isLoading = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

But When I translate the `LinearLayoutManager` is not work in Xamarin.

**Xamarin Code :**

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
```

in the upper code my `RecycleView` not found.

**UpDate :**

I have set this way

```
mRecyclerView. = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.inventory_recycleView);
var manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView. SetLayoutManager(manager);
mInventoryAdapter = new InventoryAdapter();
this.mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mInventoryAdapter);
```

but then Also my Adapter class that can not use.

```
class InventoryAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
        {

            private const int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
            private const int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 1;

            private OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener;

            private bool isLoading;
            private int visibleThresold = 5;
            private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;

            public override int ItemCount
            {
                get
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public InventoryAdapter()
            {
                var layoutmanger = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView..GetLayoutManager();

            }
}
```

Any Help be Appreciated.

Comment: LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutMgr = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()); recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutMgr );   try this

Answer (score 1):

`getLayoutManger()`, since it is a method with no arguments is converted into a property `LayoutManager` on the `RecyclerView`.

So the code will look like:

```
var layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.LayoutManager;
```

Usually you would set the LayoutManager in your Activity or Fragment like:

```
var manager = new LinearLayoutManager(Activity); // or just this if inside Activity
mRecyclerview.SetLayoutManager(manager);
```

It is unclear how you pass in your `RecyclerView` to the Adapter. It appears as if `mRecyclerView` is a field somewhere. Normally I would pass it in as an agument in the constructor if I need it in that class:

```
public MyAdapter(RecyclerView recycler)
{
    mRecyclerView = recycler;
    // do more stuff here...
}
```